# Populate javafx tablecolumn with object method call type long

Tags: methods, javafx, long-integer, tablecolumn

Sorry for the newbie question but how do you populate a javafx table column, afaik a ReadOnlyNumberWrapper does not exist.

`@FXML private TableColumn<RelationshipBO, Number> tcIncomingNodeId
tcIncomingNodeId.setCellValueFactory(
                (CellDataFeatures<RelationshipBO, Number> cellData) -> new ReadOnlyNumberWrapper(cellData.getValue().getNodeId())
        );`

getNodeID rturns a long

Thanks a lot and best regards

===

Edit: Seems like I can use the Long class in conjunction with the ReadOnlyObjectWrapper

```
@FXML private TableColumn<RelationshipBO, Long> tcIncomingNodeId;
tcIncomingNodeId.setCellValueFactory(
            (CellDataFeatures<RelationshipBO, Long> cellData) -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Long>(cellData.getValue().getNodeId())
    );
```

However any nicer solutions appreciated :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`ReadOnlyLongWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/index.html?javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyLongWrapper.html), which implements `ObservableValue<Number>` as required.